# Reliability of a relay's specification

Tags: relay

I am building a project for a consumer. It involves switching  about 20 fluorescent tubes. I don't want something to go wrong with such heavy switching. So, I was researching about the relays and looking about their specs. After some search I found out that specs on most of the cheap Chinese relays are misleading and incorrect.There are many videos online which show that the relays (SSD specifically) which were rated for higher values, had even lower rated components inside them. Also, the specifications provided by different companies relies on different testing conditions. Hence it may not be reasonable to compare two relays just on the basis of their specs.

How can I cleverly search for the correct specifications and check if the information provided on a relay is reliable? How much can I trust the rated values?

Comment: avoid cheap Chinese relays?

Comment: Split the lamps across several relays controlled by a master relay...

Comment: Buy a few test relays, conduct your own controlled experiments, and create accurate statistical data.

Comment: Go to a reputable supplier and buy from them.

Comment: _"specs on **most** of the cheap Chinese relays are misleading and incorrect. There are many videos online which show that the relays (SSD specifically) which were rated for higher values, had even lower rated components inside them."_ - many videos online are also misleading and incorrect. I bet **most** Chinese relays have specs just as reliable as those manufactured in other countries.